# UPDATE ... LIMIT 1 PostgreSQL without PK

Tags: sql, postgresql

Could you please help me creating SQL request for PostgreSQL for updating **first** record in a table without primary key?
Something like

```
UPDATE "company"
SET "salary" = 6
WHERE "name" = 'x' AND "age" = 5 AND "address" = 'x' AND "salary" = 5
LIMIT 1;
```

*Please note table doesn't have PK. It means there can be absolutely same record with same values

Comment: "first record" doesn't mean anything without an `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: Rows don't have order in a database table. Therefore, there's no such thing as "the first row".

Comment: I'm not super familiar with PostgreSQL specific syntax. Is your table name supposed to be in double quotes? `"company"`???

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: You can't. If the "WHERE" clause cannot limit the selection to one row, you really can't do what you want.

Does the rows have an intrinsic Row ID that the database itself keeps up with? If so, you might be able to use that.

Answer (score 0):

Each row in a table has a system column ctid of type tid that represents the physical location of the row:,so you can update by using ctid

```
UPDATE company
    SET salary = 6
    WHERE ctid =(0,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update exactly one row by using `ctid`.  SQL tables are *unordered*, so there is no such thing as the "first" row, but you can limit the update to one row:

```
UPDATE "company" c
    SET "salary" = 6
    WHERE "name" = 'x' AND "age" = 5 AND "address" = 'x' AND "salary" = 5 AND
          ctid = (SELECT ctid
                  FROM "company" c2
                  WHERE c2."name" = c."name" and c2."age" = c."age" and c2."address" = c."address" and c2."salary" = c."salary"
                  ORDER BY ctid
                  LIMIT 1
                 );
```

That said, I think you should put your efforts into fixing the table rather than trying to deal with data which is only going to continue causing problems.